# Android Video View - Fails to Load file from SD Card

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have an activity that uses `VideoView` and `MediaController`.

I have a .mp4 file.

1. When I put the file in `res/raw` folder, I can play the video using `Uri.parse("android.resource://&lt;package&gt;/" + R.raw.id_video)`
2. However, when I put the same file in the filesystem, it plays properly.
   I use `videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myfile.mp4");`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

can u try 
videoview.setVideoPath("sdcard/myfile.mp4);

one question.. are u using the same video view to play the video from raw folder as well?